# Is there a proper way to show different set of components on a single JFrame on Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to figure out how to show a new set of components when I click a button. For example, when you click the login button it will log you in and show you the things you can do once logged in, but I want it to be on the same window(JFrame). All I can think of to do this is to put all the components in a single window then when I click a button I will hide the other components and show the others and vice versa. Is there a proper way to do it? or at least a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to use a JPanel to group screens and use CardLayout to switch between those panels.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html for introduction to using CardLayout and a working example. Each "screen" is represented by a JPanel containing desired components:

```
//Where instance variables are declared:
JPanel cards;
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";

//Where the components controlled by the CardLayout are initialized:
//Create the "cards".
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
...
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
...

//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);
```